# JavaScript button behavior inside vs outside a form

Tags: forms, button, addeventlistener

I was looking at the addEventListener option where I wanted to create a button that increments the value of an input field each time I click on the button. My HTML code is as follows:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Learning Javascript</title>
</head>

<form>
  <input class="input" type="number">
</form>

<button class ="button">click me!</button>

  <script src="app.js">
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

When my button is OUTSIDE the form, it behaves as expected, but when it's inside the form, it doesn't increment.

This is my js code...

```
"use strict";

let inputValue = document.querySelector(".input").value;

document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  inputValue = document.querySelector(".input").value ++;
});
```

I'm just trying to understand why it doesn't work when the button is inside the form.

Comment: I suspect the solution here is to preventDefault()